# Receive Multiple array data value in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to receive multiple array in php like 3 array data .
here is my html code

i want to receive three multiple array data using php

```
Example : id : 05 , star : 03 , review : test Example : id : 09 , star : 05 , review : test new
Array date : star[] , review[] , cast_id[] 
Data Recive :  $star , $review , $cast_id


<select class="form-control" name="star[]" required>
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2 </option>
<option value="3">3 </option>
<option value="4">4 </option>
<option value="5">5</option>                            
</select>

<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="review[]" name="review[]</textarea>

<input name="cast_id[]" id="cast_id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cast_id; ?>">
```

Here I tried to receive the multiple array data and print but I only get the first array data so how can I get all data values

```
foreach($_POST['cast_id'] as $cast_id) {

foreach (array_combine($_POST['star'], $_POST['review']) as $star => $review) {

echo $cast_id."<br>";
echo $star."<br>";
echo $review."<br>";

//$reg_action = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE job_apply_review SET star = '$star', review = '$review'  WHERE cast_id = '$cast_id'");



}

}
```

thank you

Comment: what you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Example : id : 05 , star : 03 , review : test 
Example : id : 09 , star : 05 , review : test new

Comment: Why are you doing an `array_combine` on your fields? And it's not clear at all what you're trying to do here

Comment: you can pass the key in your foreach and use that to reference the corresponding entries in the other arrays

Comment: i want to receive three multiple array data using php 
Example : id : 05 , star : 03 , review : test Example : id : 09 , star : 05 , review : test new
Array date : star[] , review[] , cast_id[] 
Data Recive :  $star , $review , $cast_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array item's index to target the corresponding value in the other arrays:

```
foreach ($_POST['star'] as $index => $star) {

  $cast_id = $_POST['cast_id'][$index];
  $review = $_POST['review'][$index];

}
```